# Playing sound using an array of soundsamples

Tags: export, sound

I have an assignment where I have to apply effects such as reverb to a .wav file using mathematica. I used `Import["sound.wav","data"]` to get the array and then did some stuff with it to make the values smaller -> more quiet etc.

The problem is that I can't export the array back to a wav file (my error: reverbedsound contains no data that can be exported to the WAV format.)

I tried to turn the array back into a sound using `ListPlay[reverbedsound, reverbedsamplerate]` but it sounds a bit distorted and I hear no difference with the array of the original unedited sound.
I assume the `ListPlay` doesn't use the exact values but the ratio between them and that is what causes there to be no difference in volume?

Comment: Please add code or a small example to show us what the `reverbedsound` variable looks like.

I strongly suspect from what you've described that it's a list with samples. In that case, you would use the `Audio` constructor to play it back and to build an object to export as a .wav file.

Comment: Here's a way to add reverb: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116464/12